# Why won't this batch code work?

Tags: batch-file

Assuming that `%Edata%` was a variable written like this `"A;B;C;1;2;3;"` then this code should be able to separate it into a bunch of numbered variables:

```
set /a c=0
FOR %%A IN (%Edata%) DO (
  set /a c=%c%+1
  set var%c%=%%A
  echo.^>^>^> Set "%%A" to "var%c%"
)
```

Only the result is setting all parts of the variable to `var0` because the `%c%` variable doesn't count up each time like it's supposed to. Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a c=0
FOR %%A IN (%Edata%) DO (
  set /a c=!c!+1
  set var!c!=%%A
  echo.^>^>^> Set "%%A" to "var!c!"
)
```

The problem in your script is that variables by default are expanded at parse time and not at execution time. In this case `c` is expanded only once, before entering the loop, that's why its value is always 0 and it never changes.

You have to enable the expansion of variables at execution time with this command:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

and you have to use !c! instead of %c% inside the for loop.